# Movie or TV series episode with a kelpie or horse monster in a modern setting?

Tags: story-identification, episode-identification

I am trying to track down the name of a film or TV show I saw as a child during the 1980s. I vaguely recall a [kelpie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelpie) or water-horse type monster and some kind of long tunnel possibly a canal. I think there were children in it and they were seemingly menaced by the monster. This was live-action and not animated. I probably watched it between 1983-1986, vaguely around the same time as [The Tripods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tripods_%28TV_series%29).

I would be very interested in discovering what this was.

Probably useful to add that I am in the UK and I'm pretty sure that this is an English show or movie.

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/webhp?#q=lochness%20monster%20movies

Comment: Pretty positive it wasn't a Loch Ness Monster movie. But reasonable suggestion...

Comment: If you go [here](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/john.seymour1/telefantasylist/index.html) and click on one of the dates in the top bar, you can see a seemingly pretty complete list of all the British "telefantasies" from that year--you could go through 1983-1986 to see if any of the names ring a bell (unfortunately most don't have plot descriptions).

Comment: (...also, if you do want to check plot descriptions on any titles, you might want to download an ebook called [The Definitive Science Fiction Television Encyclopedia](http://www.scribd.com/doc/184083760/The-Definative-Science-Fiction-Television-Encyclopedia-3rd-Edition) which does have plot descriptions of pretty much every sci fi show)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to a comment by @Hypnosifl I have discovered the answer. This is most definitely **Ghost in the Water** broadcast in 1982. I would have been 5 at the time. This is based on a [book by Edward Chitham](http://www.amazon.co.uk/GHOST-THE-WATER-Edward-Chitham/dp/B003EEJU8W)

Although I have yet to find mention of a Kelpie, it involves ghosts and the tunnel is the giveaway (still gives me the heebeegeebees):

[image]
[image]

Here it is:

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the timeframe is correct, and that it is NOT one of the various Loch Ness Monster films that came out in the 80s or 90s, it could be one of these:

### Baby: Secret of the Lost Legend

Released in 1985. A husband and wife team of anthropologists in Africa find a family of Apatosaurs living in a secluded lagoon. They must then protect the herd from poachers led by a rival scientist.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby:_Secret_of_the_Lost_Legend

### Frog-Dreaming (aka The Quest)

Released in 1986. Marketed in the U.S. as "The Quest", Frog-Dreaming is about an American boy who moves to the Australian Outback. Along with his new friends, the boy begins to investigate the local legend of The Donkegin - a monster which inhabits a secluded lake.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frog_Dreaming

Comment: Definitely not either. I am pretty certain the show is from the UK. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: @Frank_Zafka no problem - any additional details you can remember will help us narrow it down more.

Comment: unfortunately this is one of my earliest memories, so that's the limit of the detail. It definitely had the feel of a Dr Who or Tripods episode...

Comment: I remember Baby... that African tribe with their recurring catchphrase of "No problem!"